# In dataframe of strings AND floats, cast floats to integer then string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe of dtype `object`:

```
  col1 col2  col3
0  1.1  3.3  spam
1  2.2  foo  eggs
2  bar  4.4   5.5
```

I would like to cast all the floats to integers then convert everything to strings, so the output would be of dtype `string`:

```
  col1 col2  col3
0    1    3  spam
1    2  foo  eggs
2  bar    4     5
```

Is there something that allows me to cast a dataframe to an int but ignore errors?  Or achieve this in a different way?  (using the `errors = 'ignore'`, seems to ignore the entire thing)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, could you please leave a comment explaining what I could do better next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a helper function that:

- tries to convert what's in your object to a `float` - so "2.5" and "2" will be able to be translated (as well as anything that Python's `float` function can interpret as a `float` value), but "hello there. how are you?" won't...
- then tries to convert that `float` to an `int`
- then returns its `str` value

If the `float` conversion fails - then it'll just return your original object as technically only the `float` conversation can fail, as if that succeeds you can always `int(some_float)` and `str` will always work (failing some weird custom class - that deliberately causes it to fail).

eg:

```
def try_to_int(obj):
    try:
        return str(int(float(obj)))
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return obj
```

Then use it with `new_df = df.applymap(try_to_int)`

Comment: This pointed my in the right direction, what I ended up using was (mostly cause it's a one-liner): 
`df.applymap(lambda x: int(x) if isinstance(x, float) else x)`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to cast to string and then use a regex to remove the decimals.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1.1, 2.2, 'bar'], 
                   'col2': [3.3, 'foo', 4.4], 
                   'col3': ['spam', 'eggs', 5.5]})

df = df.astype(str).replace(r'(\-?\d+)\.\d+', r'\1', regex=True)

# returns:
  col1 col2  col3
0    1    3  spam
1    2  foo  eggs
2  bar    4     5
```

Comment: Although this works, I cannot imagine a world where regex is the best solution to this problem.